# Java EE web application, link to the project's root folder

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications

In my java webapp, I would like to create a  link to the main page with :

```
<a href="/"> My Main title... </a>
```

But I'm redirected to http://myserver.com:8080/ and i'd like to be redirected to http://myserver.com:8080/myProjectName/

How can I do this without writing every link with

```
<a href="/myProjectName/myPageAlias"> My Main title... </a>
<a href="/myProjectName/myPageAlias2"> My Main title... </a>
<a href="/myProjectName/myPageAlias3"> My Main title... </a>
```

but just

```
<a href="/myPageAlias"> My Main title... </a>
<a href="/myPageAlias2"> My Main title... </a>
<a href="/myPageAlias3"> My Main title... </a>
```

NB : I'm not using spring or whatever...

Thanks